# Адаптивность CSS

Tags: css3

Всем привет! При открытии в окне в 100% масштабе все хорошо, но если сделать ширину браузера меньше, все сползает.

Как сделать адаптивно?

```css
#hat_logo_div {
  width: 20%;
  height: 4em;
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#hat {
  width: 40%;
  height: 4em;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: -4em;
  max-height: 4em;
}

#inst {
  width: 5%;
  max-width: 5%;
  height: 4em;
  max-height: 4em;
  background-image: url(instagram_logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -4em;
  max-height: 100px;
}

#vk {
  width: 10%;
  max-width: 10%;
  height: 4em;
  max-height: 4em;
  background-image: url(vk_logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
  margin-left: 65%;
  margin-top: -4em;
}

#auth {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: 4em;
  max-height: 4em;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 70%;
  margin-top: -4em;
}


}
#but {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 2em;
  max-height: 2em;
  border: 5em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  font-family: comic sans ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href='##'>
  <div id='hat_logo_div'></div>
</a>

<div id='hat'></div>

<div id='inst'></div>

<div id='vk'></div>

<div id='auth'>
  <a href='#'><button id='but'>Вход/регистрация</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Использовать медиа запросы конечно же. Но перед созданием вопросов впредь, погуглите, много нового узнаете, нежели ждать ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: я гуглил, все твердят про max-width, я попробовал мне не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте не указывать width в процентах и вообще не ставить width, сделайте флексовый контейнер, задайте элементам `max-width`, и укажите до скольки блоки могут растягиваться. Я бы так сделал

Comment: Михаил,а как сделать адаптацию при сжатии?

Comment: Используйте bootstrap. 
Или подход mobile first. 
Или разделяйте на блоки и используйте display:inline-block;